# Как при клике плавно перейти на следуищий блок средствами JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть два блока.Нужно чтобы при нажатии на стрелку плавно страница скроллилась вниз на следуищий блок  в моем случае розовый блок.*Ответ нужно без использовании средств jQuery*.

```css
.main-block {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:cadetblue;
}
.second-block {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:pink;
}
h1 {
    display:inline;
}
.arrow-bottom {
    padding-top: 6px;
    position: relative;

    background-color: transparent;
    min-height: 24px;
    line-height: 48px;
    z-index: 8;
}
.icon-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 31px;
    font-size:18px;
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-arrow-down {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%,20%,50%,
    80%,100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="arrow-bottom">
    <p class="icon-arrow">
       <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="second-block">
  <h1>Next block</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Изучите [вот этот вариант реализации](https://codepen.io/AnotherLinuxUser/pen/eZxoQp), он более сложный, но тоже на чистом JS, для общего понимания пригодится. Вопрос хороший, ставлю +1

Comment: @VladSpirin спасибо я как раз искал что нибудь подобное

Comment: Сделайте [модуль](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures-module) и он у вас будет на все случаи жизни (универсальный так сказать).

Comment: @VladSpirin спасибо за полезную инфу я и незнал про модули.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как пример: (надо поймать вашу стрелку )) )

```js
function down(){
var item = document.getElementById("anchor");
var topPos = item.offsetTop;
window.scroll({top: topPos, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

```css
.main-block {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:cadetblue;
}
.second-block {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:pink;

}
h1 {
    display:inline;
}
.arrow-bottom {
    padding-top: 6px;
    position: relative;

    background-color: transparent;
    min-height: 24px;
    line-height: 48px;
    z-index: 8;
}
.icon-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 31px;
    font-size:18px;
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-arrow-down {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%,20%,50%,
    80%,100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="arrow-bottom">
    <p class="icon-arrow">
       <i onclick="down();" class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="anchor" class="second-block">
  <h1>Next block</h1>
</div>
```